# VLC Play music from folder

Tags: command-line, audio, vlc-media-player

I want my VLC to play all mp3s from `E:\Music` when I open it, but Im really confused with all those commands, I tried

> vlc -LZ E:\Music

and it worked for the first time, but not when I closed VLC and then opened it, I would need to write that command again. Is there any way that VLC will do this command every time automatically when I open it?

Thx for any help.

Comment: Make a batch file with that command-line in it, and then use that batch file to launch VLC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't mention what Operating System you are using, so I'm going to give you a Windows answer.

Find a shortcut to VLC.  If using Windows7/8/10, press your Windows key, and type VLC.  You should see a couple entries for "VLC Media Player."  Right Click on the one that says "VLC Media Player", and then choose "Send To---Desktop."

Find the shortcut on the desktop you just made and right-click it and go to properties.

There is a line called "Target".  Find that.

On my copy of VLC (installed to default) the target lines reads.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"

add to the end of that  -LZ E:\music

So it looks like this.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -LZ E:\music

On the general tab of the shortcut, i'd change the name to something else besides "VLC Media Player", maybe "VLC Playing Music Folder" so you know what that shortcut does.

Press ok at bottom of shortcut properties page, and try loading your new shortcut.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. One more thing is there any way that I can add this shorcut to Windows 10 Start menu?

Comment: You can right-click the shortcut and choose "Pin to Start" and it will put a shortcut on the "Tiles" section of the start menu.  It by default goes to the bottom but you can drag it up higher.

Answer (score -1):

Create a file called `test.bat` (or whatver you want to call it).

Inside that file, enter the following:

```
start vlc --fullscreen  --loop  "E:\music"
```

This will start vlc and play the music in e:\music.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/846453)

Comment: @Burgi whilst the question is a little sparse, I'm pretty sure it is answering the question and therefore would not be valid as a comment.

Comment: @Darren you have essentially totally rewritten the answer. It is now nothing like the answer I reviewed. I'm not entirely sure that was the correct thing to do.

Comment: @Burgi I really didn’t. I added some context, the actual suggestion of creating a .bat and the contents of that are still there.

Comment: @Darren. Regardless of who is right or wrong please cut out the abusive language (which is against our [CodeOfConduct](https://superuser.com/conduct)